# Space above elements in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a situation where there is some random space above UI elements in a `ConstraintLayout`. In the image - see the space above the `textInput` and `seekBar` elements.

We're building a form of custom fields based on their types - e.g. number input, text input, a switch, etc. We build the form dynamically based on the `JSONArray` of field types and content we receive.

Everything builds perfectly, except for three types: number input, text input and a slider (`seekBar`). I'm not providing the code generating the form, because I argue that if there was something in that code, there would have been this space above each fragment and not just these three specific types.

[image]

Here is the layout file for the number input (it looks exactly the same as the one for the text input except for the input type and the element ids):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="our.package.name.custom_fields.type_slider.SliderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displayText">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/number_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the layout file for the SeekBar:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="our.package.name.custom_fields.type_slider.SliderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/slider_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displayText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being the way I'm chaining the elements.

I thought the `TextView` is the "anchor" so I constrained its top, left, right and bottom to the parent. Then I chained the other element(s) to it - the top of the `TextInputLayout` was constrained to the bottom of the `TextView`.

When I changed that around, the space issue was resolved.

So now, the top, left, right and bottom of the `TextInputLayout` is constrained to the parent and the bottom of the `TextView` is constrained to the `TextInputLayout`.

[image]

Behold:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="our.package.name.custom_fields.type_slider.SliderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input_layout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask the `TextView` to be center in his parent and then you asked from `TextInputLayout` to be below the `@+id/displayText`.
Try to change the centered of this controller:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Indeed that was the solution. I posted my answer explaining that literally 2 minutes after you posted your answer, so I didn't see it in time. Sorry! :|

Comment: Any idea WHY this is the solution?